# How to update price dynamically based on quantity using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build  a shopping cart where I want to update the price based on Quantity..But the problem I'm facing is using following javascript code that for the first item i could update the price based on Quantity but for the second item or next item i couldn't ..Can anyone help me out to find the Error please.

Here's my html :

```
<td class="total_price table-default total" >${{$row->price}}
            <span></span></td>
            <td class="qty table-default">
            <input type="number" class="quantity" value="{{$row->no_of_items}}" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /> &times;${{$row->p_price}}
```

Here's the jQueryPart:

```
$(".quantity").change(update); 

    function update()
    {
        var qty = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var net = parseFloat(document.getElementById("net_price").value);
        var total = qty * net;
        $('.total').html("$"+total); 
    }
```

Comment: This `$("#quantity").each` doesn't make sense since there can be only one element with a given ID. Use a class name instead of an ID.

Comment: can you suggest one efficient one?
i might not be pro in Javascript.

Comment: Now that you've changed your HTML to use a class name instead of an ID you can change your JavaScript back as it was. `$(".quantity").each(function update(){......})`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following block:

```
$("#quantity").each(function(i){
```

so the function is:

```
function update(){
    var qty = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var net = parseFloat(document.getElementById("net_price").value);
    var total = qty * net;
    $('#total').html("$"+total); 
}
```

Comment: but the problem is it's not getting updated for every product in cart..for the first product when i change the quantity it's getting updated..but for the second one not..and so on..